# String array to string with an external parameter

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a small question.

I have a string array and on the basis of a parameter I need to store the values of the array into a string.

```
string[] x={"A","B","C","D","F","G"};
for(int i=0;i<number;i++)
{
string y=y+","+x[i];
}
```

If **number=3**, then my string should have (A,B,C,D)

The above implementation throws an error that y cannot be used.

What should be the right kind of implementation to achieve the above functionality?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Anurag

Answer (score 4):

You could try a simple LINQ statement:

```
var partOfString = string.Join("", x.Take(number));
```

If you want to pass in `3`, but get 4 records, just add 1:

```
var partOfString = string.Join("", x.Take(number + 1));
```

If the format you want is literally `(A,B,C,D)`:

```
var partOfString = string.Format("({0})", string.Join(",", x.Take(number + 1)));
```

Comment: Let me try..Thank you

Comment: He's joining with `,` and number 3 results in 4 characters, not 3.

Comment: No Mr. Grant..I just want the records..no parentheses..I am trying the solutions mentioned here..Spare me some time..Thank you

Comment: thank you people..I was able to solve this..It was a small stuff but I was not getting it...:)

Answer (score 1):

Modified version of your code.

```
string[] x = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "F", "G" };

string result = string.Empty;
int number = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < number + 1; i++)
{
     result = result + "," + x[i];
}
result = result.TrimStart(',');
```

or simple LINQ

```
string[] x = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "F", "G" };
int number = 3;            
string result = string.Join(",", x.Take(number+1)); ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string y = String.Empty;
string[] x={"A","B","C","D","F","G"};

for(int i = 0; i < x.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    y = y + "," + x[i];
}
y = y.TrimEnd(',');
```

And please use the StringBuilder Class for manipulating string.